# How do I disable the href link on this code so that it doesn't return Void(0) on the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm displaying a woocommerce notice with a popup shortcode inside. When you try to click it, it works but redirects the URL to ' /void(0 '. How to amend this code to prevent this from happening. Thanks

```
 $message = __( 'Please Sign Up or Login', 'my-plugin ' ) . do_shortcode('[arm_form popup="true"]');

 wc_add_notice( $message );
```

Comment: Please change the plugin code .
Go to popup-anything-on-click/includes/shortcode/popupaoc-popup-shortcode.php
find the code line no 79 to 84 https://prnt.sc/q882pq
just replace the code “javascript:void(0);” to “#” this way https://prnt.sc/q883t9

Note:-In the future if plugin will update your code will lose.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not using this plugin unfortunately, I can see in my member plugin (https://codecanyon.net/item/armember-complete-wordpress-membership-system/17785056) there's some strings that are similar, the issue is theres hundreds of times this is used, is there a way I can narrow down which one it is that's causing the issue?

Comment: are you using wordpress

Comment: Yes using Wordpress

Comment: @Basharmal Thank you for your help in the right direction, I've posted an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a plugin called AR Member , I had to change the following:

wp-content/plugins/armember/core/classes/class.arm_member_forms.php
Line: 1699

Before:

```
$popup_content .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="' . $popupLinkID . '" 
class="' . $popupLinkClass . ' arm_form_popup_ahref" ' . $popupLinkAttr . '>' 
. $link_title . '</a>';
```

After:

```
$popup_content .= '<a href="#" id="' . $popupLinkID . '" class="' . 
$popupLinkClass . ' arm_form_popup_ahref" ' . $popupLinkAttr . '>' . 
$link_title . '</a>';
```

The downside is that when the plugin updates I will have to update it again, maybe someone could advise if this can be pulled into theme functions in some way?

Thanks to @Basharmal for a pointer in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the plugin code .
Go to

```
popup-anything-on-click/includes/shortcode/popupaoc-popup-shortcode.php
```

find the code line no `79` to `84` `prnt.sc/q882pq`
just replace the code

```
“javascript:void(0);”
```

to

```
“#”
```

this way

```
prnt.sc/q883t9 Note:-In
```

the future if plugin will update your code will lose